# Error: Unknown provider: $compileProvider from angular-meteor.template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, console, angular-meteor

I'm trying to build a website using [Angular-meteor](http://angular-meteor.com/) for which I'm following [the tutorial on their website](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial). I'm currently at [step 8](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial/step_08) and although things seem to work fine for now, I see an error in the console:

```
Error: Unknown provider: $compileProvider from angular-meteor.template
```

I tried undoing some things, but I have no clue when this error occurred for the first time, since this is the first time since I started the tutorial that I open the console.

Does anybody know what this means, where the error originated, and most importantly, how I can solve it? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
My app definition in `client/lib/app.js` looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('socially', ['angular-meteor', 'ui.router']);
```

and my controllers. `client/parties/controllers/partiesList.js`

```
angular.module('socially').controller('PartiesListCtrl', ['$scope', '$meteor', function($scope, $meteor){
    $scope.parties = $meteor.collection(Parties);
}]);
```

and `client/parties/controllers/partyDetails.js`:

```
angular.module("socially").controller("PartyDetailsCtrl", ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$meteor',
function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor){
    $scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId, false);
    $scope.save = function(){
        $scope.party.save().then(function(numberOfDocs){
            console.log('save success doc affected', numberOfDocs);
        }, function(error){
            console.log('save error', error);
        });
    };
}]);
```

and `/client/routes.js`:

```
angular.module('socially').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
    .state('parties', {
        url: '/parties',
        templateUrl: 'client/parties/views/parties-list.ng.html',
        controller: 'PartiesListCtrl'
    })
    .state('partyDetails', {
        url: '/parties/:partyId',
        templateUrl: 'client/parties/views/party-details.ng.html',
        controller: 'PartyDetailsCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/parties');
}]);
```

Comment: Have you injected all your dependency correctly ['dep1,'dep2, function(dep1,dep2){
  // ...
     }
forgetting to inject your dependency may cause the problem

Comment: @ShankarRegmi - I'm rather new to all this, so I'm unsure whether I injected the dependencies correctly. I added some files to my question: `app.js`, `partiesList.js`, `partyDetail.js` and `routes.js`. Can you subtract the problem from these files?